# Google Maps iOS SDK Night Mode

Tags: ios, google-maps

Is there a way of implementing a night mode in Google Maps iOS SDK considering the fact that there is NO documented property for doing so?

Comment: Somewhat related: `EDSunriseSet` is the best way to check if the current time is day/night. https://github.com/erndev/EDSunriseSet

Answer (score 1):

The latest Google maps iOS SDK (Version 2.1) does include some map styling.

You can read about implementing night mode in the [Google Maps SDK Docs.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/styling)

Also, you can take a look at the [update notes.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases)

Answer (score 0):

No - at least not with the current Google Maps SDK (1.8.1). There is no way to apply custom styles to the map.